# Vim colorscheme background not filling terminal

Tags: vim, lxterminal

I am using vim with lxterminal, and the colorscheme [kolor](https://github.com/zeis/vim-kolor), and I am experiencing an issue where vim's background color does not fill the entire terminal.

[image: vim background]

It can be seen clearly at the bottom of this screenshot, as you can see the color of my terminal. My .vimrc is as follows;

```
syntax on          " Enable syntax highlighting

set number         " Enable line numbers
set smartindent    " Automatically indent text
set tabstop=4      " Set tab width to 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4   " Indent text when using '>'
set expandtab
set nocompatible   " Disable compatibility mode (prevent ABCD key bugs)
set viminfo=

filetype plugin on " Enable filetype plugins

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ino set filetype=cpp " Alias arduino (ino) files
```

I have tried changing my `TERM` environment variable to `screen-256color`, but to no avail. `TERM` is currently set to `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change change LXTerminal theme to kolor also, because from what I see, you are using solarized for the terminal.

Comment: That sounds like a bit of a pain, seeing as in the future I may want to change my terminal (or vim) themes, without changing the other. Is there not an easy way to force vim to change the entire window's color?

Comment: I don't know of one, for terminal/vim schemes I use https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-builder which generates themes for both. I use termite for my terminal.